# Is there an equivalent to $A.get("$Browser.formFactor") in LWC?

Tags: mobile, lightning-web-components

We want to perform different logic in our LWC component js controller if the user is viewing our app in mobile.

With aura components, we could do:

```
if ($A.get("$Browser.formFactor") != 'DESKTOP') {
    //do something for mobile only here
}
```

How can we do this with LWC?

Comment: LWC, don't know. But you can check this link:
https://coderwall.com/p/i817wa/one-line-function-to-detect-mobile-devices-with-javascript

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As of today, there is a lwc module that you can import to get it:

```
import formFactorPropertyName from '@salesforce/client/formFactor'
```

> formFactorPropertyName—A name that refers to the form factor of the
> hardware running the browser. Possible values are:
>
> 1. Large—A desktop client.
> 2. Medium—A tablet client.
> 3. Small—A phone client.
>
> Pass the form factor to the getRecordCreateDefaults wire adapter to get the default layout and object information for creating a record.

```
import { getRecordCreateDefaults } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import ACCOUNT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Account';
import FORM_FACTOR from '@salesforce/client/formFactor';
 
@wire(getRecordCreateDefaults, { objectApiName: ACCOUNT_OBJECT, formFactor: FORM_FACTOR})
accountDefaults;
```

SOURCE:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_client_form_factor

Hope that helps

Answer (score 5):

Edit Dec. 2020: Now available via `@salesforce/client/formFactor` import

---

No there is no equivalent of `$Browser.formFactor` Aura global value provider in LWC. The addition of an equivalent is under discussion.

For now, you can use [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) and [Element.getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) to make component adapt to the space available on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Please use `import FORM_FACTOR from '@salesforce/client/formFactor'`

The FORM_FACTOR can have below values based on the type of the device.
Large - If the device is a desktop.
Medium - If the device is a tablet.
Small - A phone client