# Device Detection in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

```
<aura:component>

<aura:if isTrue="{!$Browser.isTablet}">
    You are using a tablet device 
    ( <lightning:icon iconName="utility:tablet_portrait" size="x-small" alternativeText="Indicates approval"/> ).
</aura:if>
<aura:if isTrue="{!$Browser.isPhone}">
    You are using a phone 
    ( <lightning:icon iconName="utility:phone_portrait" size="x-small" alternativeText="Indicates approval"/> ).
    This message is rendered using isPhone <br />
</aura:if>
<aura:if isTrue="{!$Browser.isIPhone}">
    You are using an IPhone, If it is IPhone X, _/\_ <br />
</aura:if> 
<aura:if isTrue="{!$Browser.formFactor == 'DESKTOP'}">
    You are using a DESKTOP 
    ( <lightning:icon iconName="utility:desktop" size="x-small" alternativeText="Indicates approval"/> )
    Browser device
</aura:if>
<aura:if isTrue="{!$Browser.formFactor == 'PHONE'}">
    You are using a Phone, This message is rendered using formFactor
</aura:if>
<aura:if isTrue="{!$Browser.formFactor == 'TABLET'}">
    You are using a Table device
</aura:if>
```

Can we Do this in Lightning Web Component also?

Comment: [Migrate Global Value Providers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.migrate_gvps) documentation says: `Not yet available`

Comment: thanks you Raul

Comment: So you know if there is anything we can code like that the div section should only open when we open component onmobile

Comment: If you look at the [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/252921/4726) to the duplicated post, @pmdartus mentions about use of CSS media queries as a workaround.